# Multilevel listview - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am working on a school project and making a listView in android studio which will list all the agencies and when i click one agency it must give me all the agent details under that selected row , and when I click on the agent it should give me the contact information of the agent.

I am following this tutorial as a reference: [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-multilevel-listview-tutorial/)  and I am stuck at point no. 4

I am using android studio and not eclipse(as per this tutorial) so was wondering where to add the .helper package in android studio in order to add AlertDialogManager.java file in it.

I am a newbie in android so any help is appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: Please mention your point here, if the link fails we won't be able to chevk the issue

Comment: Sorry for late reply! I have edited my question.. Please check it now..

Answer (score 1):

You can create a package by right clicking your source directory, or any of its existing packages and selecting **New > Package**. Then inside that new package, you can right click and select **New > Java Class** to create your new class.

Step 2 of your link explains the same process.

Answer (score 0):

1. At the left side you can see two options: app and gradle script. Double Click      on app
2. Then double click on java.
3. Now there are two packages having youe app's package name.One package have **android test** in bracket.Right click on package which is not android test and select **New-->package**. Window will open, write name and press enter.